# Is a shape formed of two tangents and radii symmetrical?

Tags: geometry, circles, symmetry, quadrilateral, angle

Is the kite formed by the two tangents and radii in this image symmetrical? Is there a law or reason why? I am assuming that the two tangents are of equal length, but I can't see why. Are any two tangents that meet equal in length?
[image: Diagram]

Comment: If you were to draw a line from A to O (center of circle) than you can show that all lines of triangles ADO and ABO are the same length by several different methods.  For example, the line AO shared by both triangles is obviously the same length; and, the radii lines DO and BO are obviously the same length, therefore the third line of each triangle is the same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** any tangent line is perpendicular to the radius joining the center to the point of tangency. From that it follows $AD=AB$, because triangles $AOD$ and $AOB$ are equal.